# self adjoint properties

Tags: linear-algebra

I looking for a proof for the theorem but I have not find yet.

A link or even sketch for How it goes will be very appreciate.

A linear map is self adjoint

iff

the matrix representation according to orthonormal basis is self adjoint.

by the way is not that true for all self adjoint matrix and not just for matrices

representation according to orthonormal basis.

Thanks in advanced !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint $A^*$ of a linear map $A$ on a space with scalar product is determined by the property $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x, A^*y\rangle$ for all $x,y$. If we let $x,y$ run through the base vectors of an ON basis, then $\langle Ae_i,e_j\rangle$ is the $i,j$ entry of the matrix for $A$ and $\langle e_i,A^*e_j\rangle$ is the $j,i$ entry of the matrix for $A^*$. So if $A=A^*$ then the corresponding matrix (with respect to the ON basis considered) is self adjoint

Answer (score 1):

I try to understand what you really asking for. If I correctly understand you are looking for a theorem in literature that reflects your case. This is according to my understanding the spectral theorem [>>> here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem). From either the Cauchy or von Neumann version it should be possible to deduct directly your case. All this provided I understood well your question.